# Getting a list of mounted file systems in a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module, mount-point

I'm trying to get a path to the mountpoint of a specific filesystem in a kernel module. In a user-space tool, I could read /proc/mount to do this, but from what I've tried and read, that's not possible in kernel space.

How can I achieve this in a kernel module?

Comment: You could read the procfs source code to see where it gets `/proc/mounts` from.

Comment: try looking in linux/mount.h. I think there should be a structure that has that information.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get this from /dev/ directory also you just have to use grep and sed at that place for find correct mounting point.

Comment: I just notified you about not using signatures in your posts. Please take note of that.